# Decision for a button by input value in cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have the following code, which is responsible for the state of a checkbox slider (on/off).

When the button is on:

```
      <div _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" class="pull-right switch switch-small">
       <div _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" class="col-auto"><label _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" class="o-switch">
<input _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="true" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty"><span _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" class="switch__obj"></span></label></div>
       <label _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" for="chkAllowCancelOrReschedule"></label>
    </div>
```

And when the button is off:

```
 <div _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" class="pull-right switch switch-small">
       <div _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" class="col-auto"><label _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" class="o-switch">
<input _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="false" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty"><span _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" class="switch__obj"></span></label></div>
       <label _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" for="chkAllowCancelOrReschedule"></label>
    </div>
```

The only state that changes is that of the variable  `ng-reflect-model`

How can I check this status and if it is true, press that button, and if it is off nothing happens and the test continues?

I hope I put all the details and didn't miss something.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the value of the attribute using jQuery `.attr()`, like this

```js
cy.get('input').then($el => {
  if ($el.attr('ng-reflect-model') === 'false') {
    cy.wrap($el).check()
  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I think for your method to work though, I need to use something along those line(not after that input), because on this line is that ng-reflect-model to be manipulated: <input _ngcontent-ofr-c662="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="true" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty">

Comment: Your comment does not make any sense.

Comment: I wanted to convey that in my context I don't think that .attr() method helps me, but rather something like to get a form input's value. I tested the code in my test and it doesn't find the button I need to manipulate.